# Why = and not :?

Tags: javascript, equals

As the title says why do we use = to assign variable a value and not :
Fr instance here, in this function.
Why cannot colon be used instead of equal sign..

```
packet=new Object();
packet.color="red";
packet.type="plastic";
packet.size=function(a,b){
return a+b;
}

document.write(packet.size(10,10));
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Hey sorry.It's Javascript.

Comment: Try Pascal, it has `:=`, which at least brings you one step closer :)

Comment: I think the confusion here is that an object literal uses `:` to delineate property name and value so the OP is wondering why you don't assign property values the same way.  The answer is, of course, that the language didn't design it that way.

Answer (score 6):

Because the programming language (e.g. JavaScript) was designed to work with `=` signs instead of `:` for assignments.

There may very well be a language out there that lets you assign values with `:` but obviously not the programming language (e.g. JavaScript) that your using.

Comment: Why the downvote? +1 because this is the right answer...if a language uses `=` as the assignment operator it's because that's the way they made it to be.

Comment: +1 It's as simple as that. This is an appropriate answer.